# HTML5 canvas - drawImage not working (only when error ocures )

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a simple canvas game. I started to draw all the elements of the game using game loops (update, render function). I manage to draw the simple image, but when I try to draw an image using some of the proprieties of it's function class it is not displaying anything. Nethertheless the array bullets[] contains all the objects with the correct objects.

I observed that if I do on purpose an error, then it draw's the bullet. Why this is happening that only when an error occur it draws, but not always?

Thank you!

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Bullet class, defining it's proprieties
var Bullet = function (x,y,orientation) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = 512;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    if (orientation == 0)
    {
        var bulletImageUp = new Image();
        bulletImageUp.src = "images/bullet-up.png";
        this.image = bulletImageUp;
    }
    else if (orientation == 90){
        var bulletImageRight = new Image();
        bulletImageRight.src = "images/bullet-right.png";
        this.image = bulletImageRight;
    }
    else if (orientation == 180){
        var bulletImageDown = new Image();
        bulletImageDown.src = "images/bullet-down.png";
        this.image = bulletImageDown;
    }
    else if (orientation == 270){
        var bulletImageLeft = new Image();
        bulletImageLeft.src = "images/bullet-left.png";
        this.image = bulletImageLeft;
    }    
    this.draw  = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
    }
}

// The array containing all the bullets objects
var bullets = [];

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
// When I press a key it executes 
bullets.push(new Bullet(tank.x, tank.y, tank.orientation));
};

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    for ( i=0; i<bullets.length; i++) {
        bullets[i].draw()
    }
};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;
    update(delta / 1000);
    render();
    then = now;
};
```

Comment: Presumably, your image aren't loaded when you call `render()`. You should preload the 4 images, then in the  `Bullet()` Constructor, just point to one of the four already loaded images.

Comment: You are loading a new bullet every time you create one. You should load the images separately, store them in an array and wait till they have loaded.

Comment: Additionally, are you using a requestAnimationFrame anywhere?

Comment: Yes I am using     requestAnimationFrame(main); sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: If you create a jsFiddle example for us we can help you out much easier